# jQuery and IE8 on Window XP

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, windows-xp

I wonder which version of jQuery works with IE7 on windows XP.
Or what is wrong with MY IE7 on a windows XP machine that does not even displays correctly the example at the bottom of the page:
http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/datepicker/

Any help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Datepicker is not supported from IE. you can verify that hier: http://caniuse.com/ . One more thing to mention that IE7 is not more supported by Windows: It's out of date.